# Spring Actuator does not map to localhost:xxxx/actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application which I included Spring Actuator in `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The configuration I have is this

```yaml
management:
  server:
    port: 8200
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    metrics:
      enabled: false
  metrics:
    tags:
      application: ${my.application.name}
  health:
    jms:
      enabled: false
```

However, when I tried to check the endpoints using `localhost:8200/actuator`, my browser shows

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

In my IntelliJ IDEA, I can see the actuator tab and it seems working there, but there is no URL mapping. Can someone please help?

Comment: Check the console output or log for something like `Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'`.

Comment: @LMC I don't see this line in my log. I have another service which has its Actuator working but this line is also not found in its log.

Comment: May be you have log level at ERROR. This is the full line `27-08-2021 21:00:54.911 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver.<init> - Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'`

Comment: Try to connect using 127.0.0.1:8200

Answer (score 0):

In your yml config, you've set the management server port on 8200 not your application port. So you still need to connect to your application port (Which should be 8080, unless you've set that to be something else) to health check your application.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/reference/html/#registering-management-as-a-separate-service

Just try to call this:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator
```

Or in case you've changed the port:

```
http://localhost:{port}/actuator
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it does not work either.